# objective C: may not respond to (issue)

Tags: user-interface

I have two UINavigationController in the appdelegate.h

```
{
    UINavigationController *leftView;  
    UINavigationController *rightView;
    UIWindow *window;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *leftView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *rightView;
```

appdelegate.m

```
@synthesize leftView;
@synthesize rightView;
```

then in a different class

test.m

```
#import "appdelegate.h"
```

if I do:

```
[self leftView] pushViewController...; //(Everything is ok)
```

but if I change it to:

```
[self rightView] pushViewControll...; //it complains about ViewController may not respond to -rightView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems right; what doesn't seem right is that you're including AppDelegate.  If the code was in AppDelegate.m, it would probably work without any complaints by the compiler.

Instead, you've defined @property lines for each, but that is in AppDelegate.h, not test.h - but you're using them in test.m.  That is probably the source of the problem.

Interestingly, does the code actually run?

Comment: Yeah the code runs. What is puzzling me is that it works for leftView and not rightView and they are setup the exact same way.

Comment: Can I get a reference to the main window from test.m? if so, can I get a reference to the second subview/navigation controller?

Comment: Maybe I can do something like this rightView = [self window] objectAtIndex:1]  

then use that to do [self rightView] pushViewController...

Comment: The model files were generated by xcode but when I try to assign a value to some properties it give me that warning while other properties are ok

Comment: ah, so you are using Core Data to generate these models?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard a guess: Have you declared and synthesized a property for `rightView`, or at least provided your own manual getter?

Comment: I did everything the same for both.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *leftController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *rightView;

Comment: You should post more code, we can't tell you for certain with just some small snippets.

Comment: You declared the properties, but did you synthesize or write the setters/getters?

Comment: AppDeletegate.m

@synthesize leftView;
@synthesize rightView;

Comment: AppDelegate.h  


@class TestController;  

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
     
    
 UINavigationController *leftView;
 
 UINavigationController *rightView;
    UIWindow *window;
    
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *leftView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *rightView;

@end

Comment: You might want to post additional code back in your original post so we can actually read it.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this site and dont know how to use the formatting

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question:

If I have  a *window in the appdelegate.h/.m  can I get to this *window object from my other view controllers? like vC1.m vc2.m  if so how?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you declared a @property or method called leftView that returns the leftView ivar, but you forgot to do the same for rightView. The error is telling you that `self` doesn't respond to the selector `rightView`.